# .htacces multi-language redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a strange problem with .htaccess and google. I have multiple-different root domain with 301 redirection to main domain, and that's ok, but i have also multiple languages like so .com/sl, .com/it, .com/en, and .net/sl, .net/it, .net/en the problem is when you click on the link from google is  wwww.old-domain.com/sl and that's right, but when you click on it the url become like this www.new-domain.**comsl** so the slash is missing and of course the page does not work.

So is there a fix in htaccess? my htacces redirects are:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old-domain.com/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain.net/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old-domain.net$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.new-domain\.com$1" [R=301,L]
```

**So I have to fix this www.old-domain.comsl to www.new-domain.com/sl**

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not need the trailing `/` in your `RewriteCond`. Furthermore, you are escaping incorrectly (you need to do it in the opposite places).

Clean it up with the following and see if it solves your issue.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.old-domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.old-domain\.net$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What can I try? Do you have other `RewriteRules`? This *should* work provided you're not doing something else to rewrite it later.

Comment: I mean the url that does not work, I clean up the htacces as you suggested, and I am almost there: the old-domain.com/sl redirects to www.new-domain.com/sl but www.old-domain.com/sl redirects to www.new-domain.comsl so I dont know why is wrong... hmm

Comment: Not sure. Sorry. If you copied my code exactly. it works. I've tested it. You either have another rule or code that is causing the problem.

Comment: Yes your code is working 100%, there where also a cache problem, now all it's working fine, thank you very very much.

Answer (score 3):

I think you forgot a slash.. Try this?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old-domain.com/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain.net/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old-domain.net$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.new-domain\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```